# php Insert string into string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following string

`$original =` `'</p><p>7. Soal nomer3</p><p><b>Bacalah</b><b> </b><b>teks</b><b> </b><b>berikut</b>.</p><p style="text-indent:122">&nbsp;</span>Karena ketakutan pada bencana yang akan menimpa, maka satu per satu ikan mulai diterbangkan oleh Bangau. Namun, Bangau tersebut tidak menerbangkan ikan-ikan tersebut ke tempat yang dijanjikan, tetapi justru membawa ikan-ikan tersebut ke sarangnya. Di sarangnya, Bangau memakan ikan-ikan tersebut dengan lahapnya. Demikian seterusnya, sampai ikan-ikan di danau tersebut habis.</p><p style="text-indent:122">&nbsp;</span>Kini, tinggallah seekor kepiting di danau itu yang belum dipindahkan. Kepiting itu kemudian dibawa terbang oleh Bangau. Namun, ketika Bangau itu menukik menuju sarangnya, Kepiting melihat banyak sekali darah dan duri-duri ikan di sana.</p><p style="text-indent:122">&nbsp;</span>Kepiting kemudian menyadari kalau ia juga akan dimakan oleh Bangau yang serakah itu. Ketika Bangau menukik turun, dengan cepat Kepiting menyerang leher Bangau dengan capitnya. Bangau kemudian menggelepar tidak berdaya.</p><p style="text-indent:117">&nbsp;</span>&ldquo;Lepaskan aku! Lepaskan!&rdquo; teriak Bangau dengan suara parau. Kepiting makin memperkeras jepitannya hingga akhirnya Bangau yang serakah itu pun mati.</p><p>(dikutip dari <i>pendongeng.com</i> dengan penyesuaian)</p><p>Kepiting makin memperkeras jepitannya hingga akhirnya Bangau yang serakah itu pun mati.</p><p>Pernyataan yang <b>tidak</b> sesuai dengan isi kalimat tersebut adalah . . .</p>'`

I would like to change all `text-indent:*` to `text-indent:*px`

I did this :

```
$pattern = 'text-indent:(.*)["]';
$replacement = "text-indent:$1px";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $original);
print $text;
```

but no luck. Only the last match is change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
>
> Replacement:
>
> The string or an array with strings to replace. If this
>   parameter is a string and the pattern parameter is an array, all
>   patterns will be replaced by that string. If both pattern and
>   replacement parameters are arrays, each pattern will be replaced by
>   the replacement counterpart. If there are fewer elements in the
>   replacement array than in the pattern array, any extra patterns will
>   be replaced by an empty string.

This says that the problem is your regex.

Try this instead:

```
$pattern = '\"text-indent:(\w*)\"'
```

Comment: Please mark my answer then. Thank you in advance for the points!

Comment: Also: to explain the \w instead of \d: the \w can be run on the target string multiple times and should produce the same result.